# NSObject and NSArray classes in foundation framework showing errors

Tags: ios, xcode

My Application is working fine in simulator but when i am trying to run it in Device showing error's in NSArray and NSObject in Foundation framework classes and i am not able to build also. I am using Xcode 4.2.1 and iOS is 5.0 (Lion)

```
      <Foundation/NSZone.h>   No such file or directory found
      @interface NSAutoreleasePool : NSObject {  Expected = ' "" _asm or _attribute and some Expected ')'before NSzone
```

Can any one help me how to come out with this problem.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Check if you are using non objective c data types

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to import NSZone.h file. Using the below

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
```

would help you to access the NSZone.h class methods or variables, as NSZone is part of the complete Foundation framework.

**OR**

The framework would not be a part of your project. Add it to your project and then check.

This should solve the error you are getting.